# How to catch QEvent::LanguageChange in QObject

Tags: qt, qwidget, qobject, qtranslator

My goal is to retranslate a `QObject` subclass on the fly.

In `QWidget` it's really simple to catch `QEvent::LanguageChange`: we just override `changeEvent`. However, there is not such method in `QObject` and this is where I'm stuck.

How to catch `QEvent::LanguageChange` in `QObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply override the [`QObject::event`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) method...

```
class my_object: public QObject {
    using super = QObject;
protected:
    virtual bool event (QEvent *event) override
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {

            /*
             * Retranslation code goes here...
             */

            /*
             * Return true to prevent further processing.  This may
             * or may not be what you want depending on your needs.
             */
            return true;
        }

        /*
         * Fall through to the base class implementation.
         */
        return super::event(event);
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could put the same logic in an event filter and attach that to the `QObject` of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, are you sure your method works? I tried overriding `QObject::event()` and it doesn't get called on `LanguageChange`.

Comment: I think I got it. `QObject` must be a descendant of `QWidget` in order to receive `QEvent::LanguageChange`.